# Address not displayed properly in joomla

Tags: php, joomla2.5, typography

I have created a website named m2mreach.com , the site works well apart from having the bug in the contect us page "www.m2mreach.com/contact-us.html " the address is not showing up in this.. Here with i'm attaching the image of the bug . Kindly assist....
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same question as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538698/address-not-showing-properly-in-joomla-2-5-website) but I'll answer this as it's slightly better formatted.

The data is present, it's just the margin and padding you have applied to `address` in your css. If you remove the margin and padding it shows.
If you set the margin to `margin: 0 20px;` the address shows.

I can see that the css that is causing this is from typography.php which is part of jckeditor. I think you just need to override the style on that element.

I'm not very good with css, but this one was easy to work out. I suggest you grab [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for FireFox or use the tools in your browser (Chrome has dev tools too).

Comment: It also works when removing the `overflow: hidden;` from `div class="contact-address"></div>`.

Comment: @insertusernamehere your solution works but the alingnment is not properly set can u please help me with that .. i know how to change in chrome dev tools or Mozilla firebug  , its located in typography.php file there but somehow i am unable to find same code in the typography.php file when i open same file on my local machine as well as on live server .

Comment: I wouldn't try to change typography.php, include your css after the typography.php include and override it. If you change typography.php you'll probably break whatever you use jckeditor for